# Are there any examples of Service which handles ACTION_RESPONSE_VIA_MESSAGE

Tags: android, android-intent, sms, intentservice

Trying to make my app to be default SMS app (as it required in KitKat). [instructions](http://android-developers.blogspot.ru/2013/10/getting-your-sms-apps-ready-for-kitkat.html) are pretty clear, instead point:

> In a service, include an intent filter for ACTION_RESPONSE_VIA_MESSAGE
>   ("android.intent.action.RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE") with schemas, sms:,
>   smsto:, mms:, and mmsto:. This service must also require the
>   SEND_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE permission.

Can't really understand how to write this Service? I have tried to follow Android sources but it's still unclear.

Anyone can point me to good example how it works?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Example of sms app that register for this intent :

```
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
        if (intent != null) {
            if (TelephonyManager.ACTION_RESPOND_VIA_MESSAGE.equals(intent.getAction())) {
                String num = intent.getDataString();
                num = num.replace("smsto:", "").replace("sms:", "");
                String msg = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
                // send the data to via intent
                Intent intentService = new Intent(this, SomeClass.class);
                startService(intentService);
            }
        }
    }
```

sending msg via SmsManeger -  `smsManager.sendTextMessage(address, null, msg, piSent, piDelivered);`

Comment: Hmmm... What is SomeClass.java `Service`? Can't really understand how it works...

Comment: in my case the SomeClass is sending that message via SmsManger.sendMessage

Comment: look in my code, see how to extract the address and the message from the intent

Comment: @TomerMor: Why are you having a service start another service?

Comment: All the sending sms operation are done from one entry point,  i dont want to allow every class to send sms